# jquery TypeError: can't assign to properties of new String

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why I'm not able to do this:

```
$(".item").on('click', 'a.close', closeItem());

        function closeItem() {
            $(".item").fadeOut({
                duration: 400,
                }
            });
        }
```

and yet this works

```
    $(".item").on('click', 'a.close', function() {
            $(".item").fadeOut({
                duration: 400,
                }
            });
    });
```

why cant you replace generic handler with a declared one?

Comment: Should be `closeItem`, without parenthesis. You don't call the function, you pass it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
$(".item").on('click', 'a.close', closeItem);

function closeItem() {
    $(".item").fadeOut({
        duration: 400,
        }
    });
}
```

You need to pass the function as a parameter not call it. In the way you have done it you call the function and pass the result (`undefined` in this case) to the handler instead of the actual function.